# How to create an origin-destination (OD) matrix with vehicles count using python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy, data-science

I want to create an origin-destination matrix with numbers of same vehicles passing through origins and destinations.

please find below sample data:
`

```
+-------+-------------+--------+
|sensors|         time|vehicles|
+-------+-------------+--------+
|     s1|1/8/2021 4:00|      v1|
|     s1|1/8/2021 4:00|      v2|
|     s2|1/8/2021 4:01|      v1|
|     s3|1/8/2021 4:02|      v2|
|     s4|1/8/2021 4:02|      v1|
|     s3|1/8/2021 4:02|      v4|
|     s2|1/8/2021 4:03|      v4|
|     s4|1/8/2021 4:04|      v3|
+-------+-------------+--------+
```

expected output:

[image]

I tried the below code but it's not giving me correct result.

```
places = df["sensors"].unique()
places.sort()
od_df = pd.DataFrame(df["sensors"].values.reshape((-1, 2)), columns=["O", "D"])
od_matrix = pd.pivot_table(od_df, index="O", columns="D", aggfunc="size").reindex(index=places, columns=places)
od_matrix.fillna(0, downcast="infer", inplace=True)
print(od_matrix)
```

Any help would be much appreciated!
Thanks in Advance!!!

Comment: Please don't post [images of data](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question) instead add them in text format so that we can copy these while trying to answer your question.

Comment: How do you discern rows which represent departures from rows representing incomes?

Comment: @ShubhamSharma , I have edited my post and put the sample data in text format. Thanks

Comment: @Daweo - based on timestamp, I could know entry and exit of a vehicle

Comment: nobody here to help me on this  :(